# Logic game, 9 square cards and one big square

Tags: algorithm, logic

I'm not sure this is the right place to go, maybe some other stackexchange, tell me I would post somewhere else.

Here is my problem, I found an old game at my friends place, it's supposed to be a mind game : 9 small square cards, and you have to place them so that they all fit together, here is a picture :

[image: the game to solve]

After a few hours in front of the game i gathered that there was no real easy fair way to finish the game, and so I went the programmatical way.

This is where I'm having a hard time, I though I could just use some random functions, a big loop, and get it over with. But there is something like (4*9)^9 solutions, so it seems not that easy.

Here is the code I wrote, which is pretty useless for now :
Every time I go into the loop, I shuffle my array, rotate my cards by a random value and check if the puzzle is right, a lot of wasted cycles, but I don't know where to start to make it more efficient.

EDIT : 
Fixed code, i get a few deck with 8 cards, but no 9 cards deck, if anyone has a fix to my code, or maybe there is no solution ?

```
require 'json'

class Array
    def rotate n
        a =dup
        n.times do a << a.shift end
        a
    end
end


@grid = [[{"type"=>"p", "head" => 1},{"type"=>"c", "head" => 1},{"type"=>"a", "head" => 2},{"type"=>"o", "head" => 2}],
[{"type"=>"o", "head" => 1},{"type"=>"a", "head" => 2},{"type"=>"c", "head" => 2},{"type"=>"p", "head" => 1}],
[{"type"=>"c", "head" => 1},{"type"=>"p", "head" => 2},{"type"=>"o", "head" => 2},{"type"=>"a", "head" => 1}],
[{"type"=>"p", "head" => 1},{"type"=>"c", "head" => 2},{"type"=>"o", "head" => 2},{"type"=>"a", "head" => 1}],
[{"type"=>"p", "head" => 2},{"type"=>"c", "head" => 2},{"type"=>"a", "head" => 1},{"type"=>"c", "head" => 1}],
[{"type"=>"a", "head" => 1},{"type"=>"p", "head" => 2},{"type"=>"o", "head" => 2},{"type"=>"p", "head" => 1}],
[{"type"=>"a", "head" => 1},{"type"=>"o", "head" => 1},{"type"=>"a", "head" => 2},{"type"=>"c", "head" => 2}],
[{"type"=>"o", "head" => 1},{"type"=>"a", "head" => 2},{"type"=>"c", "head" => 2},{"type"=>"p", "head" => 1}],
[{"type"=>"p", "head" => 1},{"type"=>"c", "head" => 2},{"type"=>"o", "head" => 2},{"type"=>"a", "head" => 1}]]
@new_grid = [nil, nil, nil,nil, nil, nil,nil, nil, nil]
@used = [false, false, false,false, false, false,false, false, false]

def check_validity(card, position, orientation)
    # since I'm adding from top left to bottom, I only need to check top and left           
    try_card = @grid[card].rotate orientation     
    valid = true
    # top
    if (@new_grid[position-3])
        if (try_card[0]["type"] != @new_grid[position-3][2]["type"] || try_card[0]["head"] == @new_grid[position-3][2]["head"])
            valid = false
        end
    end
    # left
    if (@new_grid[position-1] && (position % 3) != 0)
        if (try_card[3]["type"] != @new_grid[position-1][1]["type"] || try_card[3]["head"] == @new_grid[position-1][1]["head"])
            valid = false       
        end
    end
    return valid
end


def solve_puzzle(position)
    (0..8).each do |card|
        unless (@used[card])
            (0..3).each do |orientation|
                if (check_validity(card, position, orientation))
                    @used[card] = true
                    @new_grid[position] = @grid[card].rotate orientation
                                        if position == 7 
                                            puts @new_grid.to_json                                      
                                        end
                    if (position < 8)
                        solve_puzzle(position + 1)
                    else
                        puts "I WON"
                        puts @new_grid.to_json
                    end
                    @new_grid[position] = nil
                    @used[card] = false
                end
            end
        end
    end
end


solve_puzzle(0)
```

Comment: There is no solution.  I always end up with either card 3 or 8 left out.  They either need a red top then bottom (clockwise), green/blue top and red bottom, green/blue top and yellow bottom, red bottom then red top or green/blue bottom then red bottom.

Comment: Well all these thoughts for a no solution game, such a shame ;)
At least I learned a lot ! thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use recursion with pruning. I mean when you put the current card it must match the orientation of the cards you have already put. So you eliminate many impossible situations:)

Like this:

```
    void generate(int whichPos) //whichPos is from 1 to 9
    {
       for (int card = 1; card <= 9; card++)
       {
          if (used[card]) continue;

          for (int orientation = 0; orientation < 4; orientation++)
          {
              if (orientation does match other cards from 1 to whichPos - 1 in the grid)
              { 
                  used[card] = true;
                  saveInGrid();
                  generate(whichPos + 1);
                  used[card] = false;
              }       
          }  
        }
    }

    generate(1);
```

Comment: Ok I see what you did there with the used[card], shouldn't I remove the card from my array so that my loop shrink by the time I get to the last card ?

Comment: Alright, second issue, isn't this program going to add the first card always as the first card ?

Comment: No, the whichPos is the position and the card is a separate variable. Try to implement it and understand it. The above code is pseudocode.

Comment: Yes, I'm implementing right now, but if you initialize your for loop with card = 1, you need to shuffle the deck once I guess, otherwise you are always going to try the firt card of the deck on position 0, and it's going to pass as there is nothing to try it against yet.

Comment: When whichPos is 1, you try every card - see the loop `(int card = 1; card <= 9; card++)`

Comment: I understand, but the first card will always succeed to be added as the game board is empty. So with this code you always find yourself with the first card in the first "slot". So you then skip to the second slot and you forget all the other cards.

Comment: No, nothing is forgotten. I am using recursion. When the recursion call is over, the code will go to the second card.

Comment: I've now compiled what you described in my head, and I'm just understanding the recursion part of your code (er, sorry). Implementing right now :)

Answer (score 2):

I used to do constraint programming research for a living until recently and I think I can offer some advice.

Your best option is to try generate-and-test with some sensible search heuristics and a little cunning to minimise the amount of wasted search effort.

Think of the problem this way: you have nine logical variables you want to assign, {x1, ..., x9}, where x1, x2, x3 are the bottom row, x4, x5, x6 the middle row, and x7, x8, x9 the top row.

Each variable can take on one of thirty six possible values from the set D = {(p, r) | p is a piece {p1, p2, ..., p9} and r is a rotation {0, 90, 180, 270}}.

A solution is an assignment to x1, ..., x9 from D such that each piece is used in exactly one assignment and each pair of neighbouring tiles have compatible assignments (i.e., the edges match up).

Your search should keep track of the domain of possible assignments for each variable.  In particular:

- if you assign a piece pi to variable xj, then you have to cross off all possible values featuring pi from the domains of all other variables;
- if you assign a value (pi, r) to variable xj, then you must remove all incompatible assignments from the neighbours of xj;
- if you ever delete all possible assignments from the domain of a variable then you know you've hit a dead end and must backtrack;
- if you ever reduce the set of possible assignments for a variable to a single value then you know that value *must* be assigned to this variable;
- if you want to be fancy, you can use backjumping rather than simple backtracking (this is where you backtrack on failure to the most recent conflicting decision that prevents you from assigning a variable, rather than just backtracking to the immediately preceding decision).

A good search strategy is to always choose the variable with the smallest remaining domain to try assigning next.  This way you're always looking at the variables that have been most affected by the decisions you've already made on the search branch.

Anyway, hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: Following on: start by picking an assignment for the centre tile since this will have the strongest pruning effect on the search tree.

Answer (score 1):

I think your bug is in check validity.  You don't need to check the left side of positions 3 and 6 since those are the left side of the puzzle that don't need to match the right side of the previous row.

Edit: here's the line I'm thinking of:

```
# left
if (@new_grid[position-1] && (position % 3) != 0)
    if (try_card[3]["type"] != @new_grid[position-1][1]["type"] || try_card[3]["head"] == @new_grid[position-1][1]["head"])
        valid = false       
    end
end
```

Edit 2: Check your pieces, I'm seeing the following for the center piece:

```
[{"type"=>"p", "head" => 2},{"type"=>"c", "head" => 2},{"type"=>"a", "head" => 1},{"type"=>"c", "head" => 2}],
```

which I believe should be

```
[{"type"=>"p", "head" => 2},{"type"=>"c", "head" => 2},{"type"=>"a", "head" => 1},{"type"=>"c", "head" => 1}],
```

Comment: I did one of these several Christmas's ago in perl, I'll see if I can dig up my solution which is pretty similar.  Edit: a quick search turned up nothing, guess I deleted that old script.

Comment: You were right about that fix ! Thanks, I now get a few decks of 8 cards, but still no 9 cards deck.

Comment: Edited my comment with one additional fix, a typo in your pieces.

Comment: You were right once again, i fixed my code and I'm now finding 10 or so decks of 8 cards, still no 9 cards deck. I'm leaning toward a no solution case ?

Comment: I'm now wondering if someone mixed up a piece since the 2nd and 8th pieces are the same.  Take one of your 8 piece solutions and change the remaining piece to one that work work to verify your code is good (you could get 4 solutions, one for each starting corner).  Edit: and also the 4th and 9th pieces.

Comment: Seems like i'm getting no answer still when I switch the missing card to a working one, so there must be a problem in my code, but I can't read it anymore, i'll come back later to it ^^

Comment: I'm not familiar with the language you're using here, but I'm curious if the rotate code is adding the first position of the card back on to the tail of the list in this line: `n.times do a << a.shift end`

Answer (score 1):

There is actually no solution to the squares in the image.  I made it work by changing the green/blue bottom on the right side of the last piece to a red/white bottom (like the piece above it has on the right).

Randomizing is a bad idea, it is better to do an exhaustive search where you try every possibility like Petar Minchev answered.  You may be able to speed it up by pre-processing.  Except for the first piece, you will always know either one or two of the sides you need to match.  Each type has only between 3 and 6 instances among all 9 pieces.  Imagine you have these spaces:

```
0   1   2
3   4   5
6   7   8
```

Originally I did this by filling position 4, then 1, 3, 5, 7, and finally the corners.  This found 4 solutions in 3.5 milliseconds with 2371 recursive calls.  By altering the order to 4, 1, 5, 2, 7, 8, 3, 0, 6 it dropped to 1.2 milliseconds with only 813 recursive calls because there were fewer options to put in the corners.  Thinking about it now, going in order would be somewhere in-between, but a modified order would just as fast (0, 1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8).  The important thing is that having to check two matches narrows down the number of times you will make the expensive recursive call.

```
Step[] Steps = {
    new Step() { Type = 0, Position = 4 },
    new Step() { Type = 1, Position = 1, MatchP1 = 4, MatchO1 = 0 },
    new Step() { Type = 1, Position = 5, MatchP1 = 4, MatchO1 = 1 },
    new Step() { Type = 2, Position = 2, MatchP1 = 5, MatchO1 = 0, MatchP2 = 1, MatchO2 = 1 },
    new Step() { Type = 1, Position = 7, MatchP1 = 4, MatchO1 = 2 },
    new Step() { Type = 2, Position = 8, MatchP1 = 7, MatchO1 = 1, MatchP2 = 5, MatchO2 = 2 },
    new Step() { Type = 1, Position = 3, MatchP1 = 4, MatchO1 = 3 },
    new Step() { Type = 2, Position = 0, MatchP1 = 1, MatchO1 = 3, MatchP2 = 3, MatchO2 = 0 },
    new Step() { Type = 2, Position = 6, MatchP1 = 3, MatchO1 = 2, MatchP2 = 7, MatchO2 = 3 },
};
```

Here are how my cards are setup, notice I changed one of the sides on the last card to get a solution.  1 is red, 2 is fat, 3 is blue/green and 4 is yellow.  I xor with 0x10 to signify that it is the bottom of the same color.  That way you can xor 2 types and compare with 0x10 to see if they match or you can xor a type with 0x10 to find the type you are looking for.

```
Card[] cards = {
    new Card(0x01, 0x03, 0x14, 0x12),
    new Card(0x02, 0x14, 0x13, 0x01),
    new Card(0x03, 0x11, 0x12, 0x04),

    new Card(0x01, 0x13, 0x12, 0x04),
    new Card(0x11, 0x13, 0x04, 0x03),
    new Card(0x04, 0x11, 0x12, 0x01),

    new Card(0x04, 0x02, 0x14, 0x13),
    new Card(0x02, 0x14, 0x13, 0x01),
//              new Card(0x01, 0x13, 0x12, 0x04) // no solution
    new Card(0x01, 0x11, 0x12, 0x04) // 4 solutions
};
```

When pre-processing, I want to have an array indexed by type I am looking for which will give me all the cards that have that type and which orientation the type is on.  I also throw the NextType (clockwise) in there to make comparing the corners easier:

```
public CardImageOrientation[][] Orientations { get; set; }

public struct CardImageOrientation
{
    public int CardIndex;
    public int TypePosition;
    public int NextType;
}

// Orientations[1] is an array of CardImageOrientation structs
// that tell me what cards contain a side with type 1, what position
// it is in, and what the next type clockwise is
```

Here's my main recursive method:

```
public bool Method1Step(int stepIndex)
{
    StepCalls++;
    if (stepIndex > 8) // found a match
    {
        FindCount++;
        return !Exhaustive; // false return value will keep going if exhaustive flag is true
    }

    Step step = Steps[stepIndex];
    switch (step.Type)
    {
        case 0:
            // step 0 we just loop through all cards and try them in position 4 with orientation 0
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {
                PlaceCard(i, 4, 0);
                steppedUp = true;
                if (Method1Step(stepIndex + 1))
                    // found a solution, return true (will be false below for exhaustive)
                    return true;
                RemoveCard(4);
            }
            break;
        case 1:
        case 2:
            // step type 1 we simply try to match one edge with another, find card in position we are matching with
            Card card = Cards[CardIndices[step.MatchP1]];

            // to find the actual type in that position, we take the position we are looking for, subtract card orientation, add 4 and take the lowest two bits
            int type = card.Types[(step.MatchO1 - card.Orientation + 4) & 0x03];

            // find opposite orientation where we need to put the match in the empty spot
            int orientation2 = (step.MatchO1 + 2) & 0x03;

            // looking for type that is the opposite of the existing type
            int searchType = type ^ 0x10;
            for (int i = 0; i < Orientations[searchType].Length; i++)
            {
                // try one card value that matches
                CardImageOrientation cio = Orientations[searchType][i];

                // make sure it isn't in use
                if (Cards[cio.CardIndex].Position < 0)
                {
                    // check either we are step 1 or that second type matches as well
                    if (step.Type == 1 || (
                            step.Type == 2 && 
                            (Cards[CardIndices[step.MatchP2]].Types[(step.MatchO2 - Cards[CardIndices[step.MatchP2]].Orientation + 4) & 0x3] ^ cio.NextType) == 0x10)
                        ) {
                        // get new orientation for card
                        int newOrientation = (orientation2 - cio.TypePosition + 4) & 0x03;

                        PlaceCard(cio.CardIndex, step.Position, newOrientation);
                        if (Method1Step(stepIndex + 1))
                            // found solution and non-exhaustive so return true
                            return true;
                        RemoveCard(step.Position);
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
    }
    return false; // dead end or exhaustive search
}
```

Interesting note: I wrote code to randomize the cards using the existing modified deck with 4 solutions and 9999 other decks created with random seeds between 1 and 9999.  I found 3,465 solutions spread over 1,555 starting layouts in 7.2 seconds so it averaged to about .72 milliseconds per run.  It made a total of 4.16 million calls to Method1Step().

Answer (score 1):

This problem is another form of a [tiling puzzle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover), other forms of which include [Pentominoes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentomino) and [Soduku](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudoku).

One of the most effective algorithms for solving these kinds of puzzles is [Algorithm X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm_X), developed by [Donald Knuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth). One of the best implementation techniques for Algorithm X is known as [Dancing Links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dancing_Links).

The key reason why Algorithm X is spectacularly efficient at solving the puzzles (solving Suduku in a few milliseconds is typical) is that useless configurations are removed from the search space efficiently.

For example, with your puzzle, if piece at top left has a Getafix head on the south edge, then every solution configuration without Getafix feet on the north edge just below that can be eliminated.

In terms of formulating the constraint matrix for Algorithm X, you have 9 pieces that each can be placed in 9 locations with 4 orientations, so your constraint matrix will have 324 rows, one for each possible piece placement.

Identifying the constraint columns is more complex. You'll need 9 constraint columns - one for each location, to ensure pieces aren't co-located. You'll also need a bunch of additional columns to capture the constraint that the characters crossing each edge must be compatible. There are twelve interaction points, four characters each divided into two parts - another 96 columns.

**Update**

Here's a stab at starting the constraint matrix. Let's take the first piece shown in the OP picture, which has these four parts:

- Getafix Head (North)
- Roman Head (East)
- Asterix Feet (South)
- Obelix Feet (West)

For our constraint matrix, we need

- 9 columns for positions (TopLeft, TopCentre, ... MiddleCentre, ... BottomRight)
- 9 columns for pieces (Piece1 ... Piece9)
- 96 columns for the interaction points

We construct a contraint row by listing both the things we get from a particular position, and the things that this position prevents.

- Location: TopLeft, Piece1
- Includes: TopLeftEast-Roman-Head, TopLeftSouth-Asterix-Feet
- Precludes: TopCentreWest-Getafix-Head, TopCentreWest-Getafix-Feet, TopCentreWest-Obelix-Head, TopCentreWest-Obelix-Feet, TopCentreWest-Asterix-Feet, TopCentreWest-Asterix-Head, TopCentreWest-Roman-Head
  *(Essentially, only a Roman-Feet is Ok at TopCentreWest)*
- Precludes: MiddleLeftNorth-Obelix-Head, MiddleLeftNorth-Obelix-Feet, MiddleLeftNorth-Getafix-Head, MiddleLeftNorth-Getafix-Feet, MiddleLeftNorth-Roman-Head, MiddleLeftNorth-Roman-Feet, MiddleLeftNorth-Asterix-Feet
  *(Only Asterix-Head is Ok at MiddleLeftNorth)*

Now, repeat this 3 more times for the other three orientations of this piece in the TopLeft location ...

- Location: TopLeft, Piece1
- Includes: TopLeftEast-Getafix-Head, TopLeftSouth-Roman-Head
- ...
- Location: TopLeft, Piece1
- Includes: TopLeftEast-Obelix-Feet, TopLeftSouth-Getafix-Head
- ...
- Location: TopLeft, Piece1
- Includes: TopLeftEast-Asterix-Feet, TopLeftSouth-ObelixFeet
- ...

Repeat these 4 rows 8 more times, for each of 4 orientations in the 8 remaining spaces (32 more rows, for 36 rows total).

Then, create 36 more rows for each location/orientation of the remaining 8 pieces (288 more rows).

You'll probably want to write code to generate the matrix, rather than calculate it by hand!

Comment: Can you give more of an example, maybe with what the matrix would look like for 4 or even just 2 pieces?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that knowing [prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prolog) would be a great help here, but I don't think I'm qualified to answer that. However I may be able to help you work out how likely your current solution is to work:

The 9 pieces can be placed in 9! = 362880 permutations (position only)

They can each be rotated 4 ways -> 4^9 = 262114

However you will have 4 solutions which are just rotations of each other, so /=4.

Giving an average of 23,781,703,680 possible arrangements to try before you find a solution :(